# При системном нажатии Ctrl+C уменьшается громкость

Tags: python, python-keyboard

При помощи модуля keyboard имитирую копирование текста. Уменьшается громкость на компьютере, текст не копируется.

```
import keyboard

keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl + c')
```

Какие ещё существуют способы копирования в буфер-обмену?

Comment: По моему вы не правильно указываете что нужно сделать, разве вы одновременно зажимаете клавиши на клавиатуре?

Comment: При записи 
```
keyboard.press("Ctrl")
keyboard.press("C")
keyboard.release("Ctrl")
keyboard.release("C")
```
тоже увеличивается громкость. задержка между нажатиями не помогает

Comment: Да я проверил эту комбинацию, возможно баг.

Comment: Попробуйте pynput